# How to get coordinates in every 1 minute

Tags: react-native

*I want to get my coordinates in every 1 minute even app close or background. But what ever I did, I couldnt do that. I used `background-task` but it works minimum in every 7m30s so it doesn't help me.*

*I used  `'react-native-geolocation-service'` like this :*

```
this.watchID = Geolocation.watchPosition((lastPosition) => {

    this.setState({ initialPosition: lastPosition });

    Latitude = lastPosition.coords.latitude;
    Longitude = lastPosition.coords.longitude;

     var lat = parseFloat(lastPosition.coords.latitude);
     var lng = parseFloat(lastPosition.coords.longitude);

           console.log("lat2 :",lat);
           console.log("lng2 :",lng);

},
(error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
{enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 0, distanceFilter: 1, useSignificantChanges: true});
```

*to get coordinates when I move  in every 1 meter but it keeps continue to give coordinates and never stop. And also it doesnt work when app closed.*

Answer (score 0):

[Expo SDK v32.0.0](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/location/) release includes initial support for background location.

Comment: how can I add npm of expo ?